# Installing Symfony CMF in existing project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I would like to install Symfony CMF into an existing Symfony2 project. I just want editing a few pages with CMF.

I am using this documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/book/installation.html ; just for new installation ...

Comment: And what is the problem? Can you explain better your situation?

Answer (score 0):

did you run into a specific issue?
anyway you might also find this link useful http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/editions/cmf_core.html